# Using clientHeight causes JavaScript function to fail

Tags: javascript, html, css

I set the following CSS at the top of my file:

```
#img1, #img2, #img3 {
  background: url("bates-sprite.jpeg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  object-fit: none;
}

#img1 {object-position: 0 0;
  width:  816px; // full size 3264
  height: 612px; // full size 2448
}
```

This is the relevant part of my JavaScript:

```
    var tempDiv = document.createElement('div');
    tempDiv.setAttribute("id", "bigImg" + figNum);
    // Make tempDiv High enough to hold the scaled up image.

    // This line is causing a problem
    let imgHeight = document.getElementById("img1").clientHeight;

   // let imgHeight = "1224px";
   tempDiv.style.height = parseInt(imgHeight) + parseInt("400px") + "px";
```

If I set imgHeight explicitly to 1224 pixels, the function works perfectly. If instead I use clientHeight, it fails. How can I fix it?

Comment: "Fails" ***how***? An error? Doesn't do what you expect? If so, what *does* it do? What [debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/) have you done?

Comment: Note that [`clientHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight) is a **number**, not a string. There's no reason to use `parseInt` on it. And `parseInt("400px")` seems an oddly roundabout way to write `400`. :-)

Comment: Re "`width:  816px; // full size 3264`": `//` is not a valid comment character sequence in CSS (only the C-style one is, `/*  */`). This is also indicated by the weird ***syntax highlighting***. It *will* break in some browsers (e.g., it may ignore all or part of the rest of the CSS (terminate parsing)).

Answer (score 0):

Client height will only give a number, but you need to add the type of that, also like (px, %, rem), to make it work.

Comment: You are both correct.  By “fails” I mean further statements were not executed. To debug, I printed out a simple message to indicate everything worked up to that point. Thus I was able to locate which statement was causing the problem.